# Content Security Policy with uppercase names in Chrome

Tags: security, iframe, content-security-policy

I'm using a corporate web portal where a web application is displayed inside an iframe. In the test environment, when I try to open the main application with Chrome, I get this error:

> Refused to display 'https://rbmidde02.corp.company.com/identity/server/' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://RBMIDDE02.corp.company.com"

As you can see the only difference is in uppercase and lowercase letters, but the URL is the same. The url in top bar is lowercase, as the `src` attribute in the `iframe` element, but I still get this error.

```
<iframe id="mainIframe" iframe-onload="iframeLoadedCallBack()" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" src="https://rbmidde02.corp.company.com/apps/repricer/" style=""></iframe>
```

Even changing the URL in the `iframe` to uppercase won't work, because the application triggers an identification process which url starts with "https://rbmidde02.corp.company.com/identity/server/".

Is there a way to solve this problem? Our corporate users have Chrome on their PCs, so suggesting to use firefox won't be a good tip.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to actually get this to happen (are your users' Chrome browsers up to date?). It's possible that somehow only a second-tier subdomain respects caps (as of Chrome 63, case is ignored in subdomain and domain of content security policies). I didn't have any two-tier subdomains to test this out with.

If this is somehow being read it's a browser error, as domains are case insensitive, and that's not a firefox thing.

To actually fix it you'll need to adjust your actual Content Security Policy header (or meta tag) not the iframe, that's where the caps are given the error message you're getting. Correct the CSP to lower case and it should load. Even though it really should load regardless unless some weird edge case is going on.